# How to check if the ISO was written to my USB stick without errors?

Tags: filesystems, usb, checksum

I followed [these](http://wiki.debian.org/DebianEeePC/HowTo/InstallUsingStandardInstaller) *DebianEeePC HowTo InstallUsingStandardInstaller* instructions at the Debian Wiki, to write a Debian ISO to my USB.

```
dd if=debian-*-netinst.iso of=/dev/sdX
```

Using `sha1sum`, I can check the checksums of my downloaded ISO file. How can I check the checksum of the USB stick device, to be sure that the USB stick does not have any problems and that the ISO was copied perfectly?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use `cmp` for checking if everything was copied fine:

```
$ cmp -n `stat -c '%s' debian-X-netinst.iso` debian-X-netinst.iso /dev/sdX
```

This solution does not explicitly compute the checksum of your `/dev/sdX` - but you don't need to do that because you have already done this for the source of the comparison (i.e. `debian-X-netinst.iso`).

Doing just a `dd if=/dev/sdX | sha1sum` may yield a mis-matching checksum just because you get trailing blocks (`/dev/sdX` is most likely larger than the iso-file).

Via `cmp -n` you make sure that no trailing bytes on your `/dev/sdX` are compared.

If you are paranoid about the quality of your USB mass storage device you call `blockdev --flushbufs /dev/sdX`, eject it, re-insert it and then do the comparison - else all or some blocks may just come from the kernels VM (cache) - when in reality perhaps bits on the hardware are screwed up.

Comment: why one should use -n switch to "compare at most LIMIT bytes"? sudo cmp a b is not enough to verify all corruption?

Comment: @16851556 the `-n` switch is necessary because your USB stick device is likely larger than the written ISO image. Thus, without it, `cmp` would always report a failed comparison, because it reads some trailing bytes out of `/dev/sdX` which aren't present in the ISO file.

Comment: thx, and for file to file (not file to drive) comparison one can use "sync;cmp a b", "sync;md5sum a b" or "sync;diff -b a b" or maybe just run rsync with --checksum switch i assume.

Answer (score 11):

Julien's answer does the job but there is a simpler and faster way to do this:

```
sudo head -c <image size> /dev/sdX | sha1sum
```

Comment: So, in a single line: `head -c $(stat -c '%s' the.iso) /dev/sdc | sha1sum`

Comment: Debian now only provides sha256 and sha512, so to ease copy-paste from this page I'm adding: `head -c $(stat -c '%s' THE_ISO_FILE) /dev/THE_USB_DEVICE | sha256sum`

Answer (score 7):

Just using `dd` and `md5sum` / `sha1sum` is enough, but as previously said, be carefull, your device is not of the same size than your file, so sums will differ.

Here how you still can do it

First you'll need to know the size of the file:

```
$ stat -c '%s' debian-live-8.2.0-amd64-lxde-desktop.iso
1003487232
```

Then, to be cool with your syscalls, you better get this as a multiple of a nice power of two like `4096`, the multiplication of the two HAVE TO yield exactly the size of the file, in other ways, you'll check too few or too many bytes, yielding a wrong checksum.

```
$ bc
bc 1.06.95
scale = 9
1003487232 / 4096
244992.000000000
```

I'm happy, `4096 × 244992 = 1003487232` so 4096 is good for me, (and will for you, probably) so I can use a block size of `4096` (typical) and a bloc count of `244992`.

Don't forget to write the file on the USB key...

```
$ dd if=debian-live-8.2.0-amd64-lxde-desktop.iso of=/dev/sd? && sync
```

And know, using the known block size and the block count, you can read the exact number of bytes from the key and check them:

```
$ dd if=/dev/sdb bs=4096 count=244992 | sha1sum
b0dbe4ca8f526d1e43555459c538607d4a987184
```

(Yes `md5sum` is way faster than `sha1sum` but that's clearly not your bottleneck here, the bottleneck is the USB thoughput, thanks for noticing).

Or, in short:

```
dd if=/dev/sdb bs=4096 count=$(($(stat -c '%s' the.iso) / 4096)) | sha1sum
```

Comment: Thanks with `$ dd if=/dev/sdb1 bs=4096 count=<filesize/4096> | md5sum`  I could check the md5sum of a Debian image written to a usb stick and compare it to Debian md5sums.

Answer (score 1):

Based on @Kyle Jones answer

```
diff <(md5sum debian-XYZ-netinst.iso | awk '{print $1}') <(dd if=/dev/sdX | md5sum | awk '{print $1}')
```

you should use `md5sum` because it's faster than `sha1sum` (this will save time when you check big file)

Comment: You mean `md5sum` is at least twice as fast? It has to be since the OP already has the `sha1sum` from the download site and does not have to calculate that. And reading from USB is going to be limiting factor not the sha1/md5 calculation.

Comment: I'm running ZFS with SHA-256 checksumming on a processing-power-wise mid-range system. Even during scrubs (which reads all data and verifies all checksums) on pools residing on spinning rust, the limiting factor is disk I/O throughput, not CPU. I doubt many USB memory sticks will sustain a much better throughput than that, particularly if it's connected over USB 2.0.

Comment: What about `sync && md5sum "/path/to/srcfile" "/path/to/dstfile"` ? (sync - Synchronize cached writes to persistent storage", both resulting hash must be same, else file is not identic) then: umount /usb/drive